# Add a row number to result set of a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a simple select statement. I want to add a temporary column that will represent number the of rows in my result set. I tried this -

```
declare @num int
set @num = 0;
select t.A, t.B, t.C, (@count + 1) as number
from tableZ as t
```

It assigns the 1 to all rows. I tried @count = @count + 1 and it did not work.
How do I do this thing in a simple manner?

thanks.

Comment: How do you want the row number to increment? Arbitrary? Your query doesn't have an ORDER BY, so, you need to define what you expect the ordering to be.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I only need my rows to be numbered. Order is not really necessary. Does that answer your question ?

Comment: So you're okay with the order being applied randomly, and the results being spit out to your query in an inconsistent order every time?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160970/how-to-generate-sequential-row-number-in-tsql/27150629#27150629

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The typical pattern would be as follows, but you need to actually define how the ordering should be applied (since a table is, by definition, an unordered bag of rows). One way to do that if you don't care about a specific order otherwise is to use the leading key(s) of a covering index, the leading key(s) of the clustered index, or the columns in any group by / order by clauses. In this case I'll assume `A` is the single-column clustering key for `t`:

```
SELECT t.A, t.B, t.C, number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.A)
  FROM dbo.tableZ AS t
  ORDER BY t.A;
```

If you truly don't care about order, you can generate arbitrary/nondeterministic row numbering using:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID)

-- or for serial plans

ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@TRANCOUNT)
```

*Little tricks I picked up from Paul White [in this article](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/04/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-4) (see "Paul's Solution").*

Not sure what the variables in your question are supposed to represent (they don't match).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160970/how-to-generate-sequential-row-number-in-tsql/27150629#27150629

Answer (score 128):

```
SELECT
    t.A,
    t.B,
    t.C,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS number
FROM tableZ AS t
```

See working example [at SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/94312/4/0)

Of course, you may want to define the row-numbering order – if so, just swap `OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))` for, e.g., `OVER (ORDER BY t.C)`, like in a normal `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Why does adding ```where number = 1``` or some other where clause based of `number` throw an invalid column error? Is there any way to add a where clause based on the `number` column?

Comment: @CJEdgerton Because of the way a SELECT statement is parsed/read. The WHERE clause is calculated before aliases in the SELECT list are materialized. So to work around it you can just put the SELECT in a CTE/subquery and then use a where clause when selecting from that.

Comment: this information was helpful