# How to generate sequential row number in tsql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a requirement in a report to show alternate colors in row and for this I need to generate sequential numbers in a SQL Select statement (see example below) to use later while displaying rows. 
I am trying row_number and some other techniques its not working. This should not be done using script, I should be able to generate within Select statement. Appreciate any help.

```
RowNumber - 1, Otherdata - Something1
RowNumber - 2, Otherdata - Something2
RowNumber - 3, Otherdata - Something3
RowNumber - 4, Otherdata - Something4
RowNumber - 5, Otherdata - Something5
```

Comment: Have you tried ````ROW_NUMBER()````? The syntax is like: ````ROW_NUMBER ( ) 
    OVER ( [ PARTITION BY value_expression , ... [ n ] ] order_by_clause )```` . Read more @: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Comment: I tried that but wasn't successful maybe I should take another look at it

Comment: Can you perhaps post the query you are trying to extend with row numbers, so maybe we could give you a better answer on where you go wrong with ROW_NUMBER()?

Comment: I tried row_number solution using MSDN sample provided Alex and worked this time. Thanks Alex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a row number to result set of a SQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20232641/add-a-row-number-to-result-set-of-a-sql-query)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no need to avoid Analytic Functions if your database supports them e.g ROW_NUMBER()

```
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [<PRIMARYKEY_COLUMN_NAME>]) AS Number
    FROM
        [<TABLE_NAME>]
```

The syntax is `Func([ arguments ]) OVER (analytic_clause)` you need to focus on OVER (). This last parentheses make partition(s) of your rows and apply the Func() on these partitions one by one. In above code we have only single set/partition of rows. Therefore the generated sequence is for all the rows.

You can make multiple set of your data and generate sequence number for each one in a single go. For example if you need generate sequence number for all the set of rows those have same categoryId. You just need to add `Partition By` clause like this `(PARTITION BY categoryId ORDER BY [<PRIMARYKEY_COLUMN_NAME>])`.

Remember that after `FROM` you can also use another extra `ORDER BY` to sort your data differently. But it has no effect on the OVER ()

Comment: Note: this thread is old but it jumps up in my google search.

Answer (score 3):

If sort column contains unique values,  you can also do it without the new built-in Row_Number() function, by using a subquery based on a sort column.

```
  Select [other stuff],
      (Select count(*) From table 
       where sortCol < a.sortCol) rowNum
  From table a
  Order by sortCol
```

change `<` to `<=` to start counting at 1 instead of 0

Comment: Using `row_number()` will be much faster than the co-related scalar sub-query.

Comment: Not really, `ROW_NUMBER()` is 10 years old and the subquery will result in sequential processing of all the fields. It's a definite no-no. If you can't use `ROW_NUBMER()`, a standard trick is to use an [auxiliary table filled only with numbers](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/virtual-auxiliary-table-numbers) to emulate the sequence. This trick was used before 2005, and is even enshrined in Oracle's DUAL table.

Comment: what "Not really" ??!! Are you really suggesting that knowing how to construct correlated subqueries in a variety of scenarios is "Not worth knowing about" ?   Regardless of its practical utility or performance issues in ANY specific situation, this technique is absolutely worth knowing about.

Comment: Simple and working. I need this on query without primary key. For multiple usage in the same query is worth to put it to `cross apply` section

Comment: @Panagiotis, ... and please, don't tell me you really think that using row_Number, or, or for that matter, ANYTHING, avoids *actua*l sequential processing.  The distinction we all make between sequential, row-based processing and set-based is an abstraction, which is only relevant or meaningful at conceptual levels far removed from the physical layer. Clearly, at the physical or machine level, we can only process one instruction at a time. (per CPU).

Comment: @CharlesBretana you'd be wrong. I suggest [T-SQL Window Functions](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/tsql-window-functions) for a thourough discussion and performance comparisons. In shortt, the server knows what `ROW_NUMBER()` is and uses worktables, often in memory, to calculate these results. A subquery though has to run in full. If you enable IO statistics you'll see the difference. I'm sure Aaron Bertrand or Brent Ozar will have a benchmark comparing the two techniques as well

Comment: @CharlesBretana the server and optimizer would also disagree with you, as a query `ROW_NUMBER()` results in half the actual plan cost of the subquery, and 1/3 the page reads on a query that returns 6K rows.

Comment: @JanZahradník neither simpler nor faster than the built-in `ROW_NUMBER()`. Just try both with `STATISTICS IO ON` and the actual execution plan

Comment: @Panagiotis, I don't care what the server (what's that referring to ) or the optimizer say. The Optimizer does not operate at the machine level. What concurrent operations may or may not occur at the machine level (How many bits can a single read head on a disk read simultaneously) is not determined or in any way related to how the SQL query optimizer structures the query plan.

Comment: This says little about performance. Different query plans will of course perform differently, but "Sequential Processing" is an ambiguous concept unless carefully defined at a specific level of abstraction. - and has only a tenuous connection to actual physical processing and performance.

Comment: @CharlesBretana the server means the server's statistics, IO and execution plan. The *actual* measures, not suppositions. What you call ` actual physical processing and performance`. If your assumption contradicts the facts, well, you can't change the facts

Comment: @CharlesBretana BTW [Aaron Bertrand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20232641/add-a-row-number-to-result-set-of-a-sql-query) had already answered a similar question 1 year before this one. Really, just **try** both of the queries. I didn't imagine the statistics I mentioned earlier, I tried that on a prodcution table with 6M rows, even though my WHERE clause only returned 6K rows. 29% vs 71% plan cost, 18720 vs 60155 logical reads

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos for a single purpose query I don't really care if it runs 5 or 10 minutes. My point was that this solution is simplier to write for scenario without a primary key. In my case I needed distinct results which in case of row_number would require sub-selecting.

Comment: @JanZahradník Are you confusing it with `RANK`? ROW_NUMBER doesn't generate the same number twice, nor does it care about a primary key. The only thing that affects the result is the `OVER(ORDER BY ...)` clause. Or did you mean you want to apply `DISTINCT` first without taking `ROW_NUMBER` into consideration? You could use a CTE then.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ,  You keep focusing on performance "Just try it" what, in any sense, will trying it tell me about what is going on at the machine level ? Statistics just report performance and activity of LOGICAL ABSTRACT processes occurring at the level of the Query plan, or optimizer, not at the machine level.  My comment has nothing to do with performance, it has to do with correcting a flawed conceptualization about what the term "Sequential Processing" might imply, or what it might mean. (if anything)

Comment: +1 to offset the twerps who think that there’s anything intrinsically wrong with this solution. This is 2018 and I have students who run versions of DBMS software which don’t yet support Window Functions. OK, so I tell them to upgrade, but that’s not always something they can control. My testing in Microsoft SQL shows that Window Functions are about 7 times faster, but, even if that’s 14 seconds compared to 2 seconds, it’s a solution.