# How can I use MySQL ROW_NUMBER Function in a query

Tags: mysql, window-functions, row-number

I am trying to learn about the MySQL ROW_NUMBER() function and how to use it to generate a sequential number for each row in a result set.

What I tried so far:

```
SELECT e.*, 
ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER(PARTITION BY e.examid ORDER BY e.examid) AS id 
from exam e
```

When I run this query, a series of errors were displayed:

> 3 errors were found during analysis.
>
> ```
> An alias was previously found. (near "id" at position 68)
> An alias was expected. (near " " at position 67)
> Unexpected token. (near "id" at position 68)
> ```
>
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY examid ORDER BY examid) as id from exam LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

How can I go about it?

Comment: [MySQL 8.0 supports ROW_NUMBER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql/46753800#46753800)

Comment: And more to the point, MySQL < 8.0 does _not_ support ROW_NUMBER. What version are you using? `SELECT @@version;`

Comment: @BillKarwin, 5.7.14

Comment: So indeed, this explains why you can't use features that are not available before MySQL 8.0.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160970/how-to-generate-sequential-row-number-in-tsql/27150629#27150629

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This syntax works in my case:

```
SELECT
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id)) row_number, Field1, Field2
FROM
    myTable
ORDER BY
    id
```

Additional remark: `select version()` returns `10.3.20-MariaDB-log`.

Comment: parentheses - is all I had to add to give an alias. that's excellent, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change the I'd to something else because the select * statement will return an id and it will conflict with that I'd (AS id)