# How to set value to variable in select query in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, variables, sql-server-2012, setvalue

I want to generate a sequence for a complex query. For that purpose I have used a variable `@rowNo`.

My logic is :- 
If a field - `isremoved = 0` then increase row number by 1.
If `isremoved = 1` then increase row number by 1 only once till you find next 0.

This is so far I have done, but it gives me syntax error.

```
DECLARE @rowNo INT;
SET @rowNo = -1;

SELECT
case when sampleTable.isremoved = 0 then @rowNo + 1
    else @rowNo end
as rowNumber,
X,
Y,
Z
.
.
FROM tbl_sample sampleTable
INNER JOIN tbl_sample_2 sample2 ON sampleTable.id = sample2.id
.
.
.
```

This is my desire output :-

[image]

So what is the right way to achieve this kind of functionality in `sql server 2012` ?

EDIT :-
I do have one solution to use sub query to retrieve row number. But that will hit performance as it is very complex query (more than 20 joins) with huge amount of data.
So please suggest me an alternative.

Comment: Have a look at this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20232641/add-a-row-number-to-result-set-of-a-sql-query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20232641/add-a-row-number-to-result-set-of-a-sql-query)

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I apologize for confusion. I have updated question. Image represents my outcome perfectly in case you are still confused.

Answer (score 1):

one way to do this is with subquery:

```
Select (Select count(*) from tbl_sample
        where id <= a.id 
            and a.isRemoved =1) rowNumber,
   X, Y, Z
From tbl_sample a
     Join tbl_sample_2 b 
         On b.id = a.id
```

Comment: It is very complex query (almost 20 joins). So This kind of solution hit performance.

Comment: Yes, it will, but, assuming one of the id columns is a Foreign Key, if you put an index on it, that will minimize the performance hit.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012+, you can do what you want with a cumulative sum:

```
SELECT sum(case when sampleTable.isremoved = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over
            (order by . . .)
       . . .
```

The `order by` should repeat the `order by` in the outer query.  You can also try using `order by (select null))`.  In my experience, this uses the ordering of the data in the outer query, but this is not documented to always work.

SQL Server does not allow you to set variables in a `SELECT` and to return values in a result set.  One or the other, but not both.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your `rowNumber` logic is equivalent to: if previous `isremoved = 0` then increment `rowNumber` by 1, otherwise keep it as it is.

Using a combination of `LAG` and `SUM ... OVER` you can easily implement this logic:

```
SELECT id, isremoved,
       SUM(IIF(prevFlag = 0, 1, 0)) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rowNumber
FROM (
SELECT a.id, isremoved,
       COALESCE(LAG(isremoved) OVER (ORDER BY a.id), isremoved) AS prevFlag
FROM tbl_sample AS a
INNER JOIN tbl_sample_2 AS b ON b.id = a.id) AS t
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/658f2/1)

Comment: Your solution is right for POC. But it does not work with my actual query. I will get back with exact question soon.

Comment: This is the right solution. But there is one issue, I am using `order by`. That changes row number. Demo here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5a30f/2

Comment: @unknown I'm not sure I understand what your actual requirement is. If your rows are ordered by `seq` instead of `id` then use this field in the `OVER` clause of the window functions instead of `id`.

Comment: I just want to apply 'order by' on result. Do not confuse with the name seq. Lets assume that there is a name field I am trying to order by. The same would happen.

Comment: Please demo here :- with order by http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/64fd3/2 & without order by http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/64fd3/3

Comment: @unknown So you want to not order by `id` but by another field and still get `rowNum` to respect this other order?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want to achieve.

Comment: @unknown This is not possible. It's like wanting to order a single field in two different ways at the same time.

Comment: It can be achieved by this query :- `SELECT * FROM (SELECT seq, [other_field] FROM tbl_sample....) as sampleAlias order by sampleAlias.seq`

Comment: @unknown This query orders records by `sampleAlias.seq`. `rowNum` field will be out of sync though as it produced on the basis of `id` order.