# SQL Server 2008 : need a way of adding row numbers for just in the Select statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, cognos

I have the following `Select` statement:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT MAX(BDCRNumber)
      FROM RHIBDCRAdjustmentDetails) + /*  need a way of numbering the columns */ AS Number,
    OverrideCategory,
    GetDate() AS CurrentDate,
    PayeeID,
    OperatingUnit,
    ProductID,
    Currency,
    OverrideSupervisor,
    OverrideAmount,
    CauseCategory,
    BonusAdjType,
    Comment
FROM
    ManagerialOverrideBDCR
WHERE
    SupervisorID <> OverrideSupervisor
    OR Amount <> OverrideAmount
```

The engine is SQL Server 2008 and I need a way of adding row numbers to the `select` statement because I am using a third party software to run the statement so I am very limited into how to solve this problem. Please help

Comment: Have you looked at the ROW_NUMBER windowing function?

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer to this is google:  "sql select row number"

Example : [Add a row number to result set of a SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20232641/add-a-row-number-to-result-set-of-a-sql-query)